# Environment Variables in Rstudio on Mac

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio

I have an environment variable that I can print from the terminal:

```
echo $STATTLE_TOKEN
```

returns

```
"ALKJSLKJLKFJALSKJFLASJFLSAF"
```

When I am in ipython, I can print it using:

```
import os
os.getenv("STATTLE_TOKEN")
```

which prints

```
"ALKJSLKJLKFJALSKJFLASJFLSAF"
```

However when I fire up a new Rstudio session,

```
Sys.getenv("STATTLE_TOKEN")
```

yields

```
""
```

What am I missing?  I want to leverage my system's environment variables, but obviously I am not connecting the dots onto something.  I would prefer not to have to put it in a file that loads on startup for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably start your interactive Python differently from your RStudio session.  The outcome suggests that iPython may be a child process -- maybe you launched it from the shell?

The key will be to make R(Studio) aware of these environment variables. You could always set them explicitly in `${R_HOME}/etc/Renviron.site`.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in.  I just opened up ipython in a simple terminal.  Rstudio is the default when opening up the app.  On my windows machine, RStudio looks at the system, but on my mac it looks like the behavior is different.  is the standard way to define them as you noted above?

Comment: That is up to you. I know where to set them in Linux; I vaguely remember what I had to do when forced to deploy Windoze, but I am nowhere fancy enough for owning an OS X box so for that it is between and Cupertino...  Kidding aside, `Renviron` and `Renviron.site` _will_ be read by R. Which is what you want.

Comment: Mac GUIs often have a different $PATH than the bash shell would be seeing.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is not `$PATH` but otherwise related to the same issue: how the application in question is started.  And if OS X 'hides' those values we have to add them in again. Hence `Renviron.site` to set them.

Comment: I am on OS X and have had enough of these problems with R processes that are child of RStudio or Emacs/ESS that I always use user- or project-level `.Renviron` for this.

Comment: I don't use environment variables much but when I do I generally want them in _all_ sessions for _all_ users hence `Renviron.site`.

Comment: On my system in the MacGUI, I see quite a few more environment variables set when I execute `system("printenv")` than when I execute `printenv` in a bash session. The results of `Sys.getenv()` are different across the RStudio and MacGUI as well. I don't see any "hiding" in any case.